# Enable authentication via Twitter (OAuth)

Tags: feature-request, login, twitter

This is more a curiosity than a request (I prefer using my Gmail account to log into sites); is there a particular reason that users can't log into the Stack Exchange network with a Twitter account, or other OAuth services?

My initial thought was that SO only supported OpenID, but it has a Facebook Connect setup running, which means you have Google, Yahoo, and FB; seems like Twitter is an obvious missing piece here.

I wonder because I was considering trying to setup an OAuth/Twitter sign-in capability for my own site. What's the reasoning there?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Facebook and Twitter aren't really the same type of provider.

Yes yes, they both use "OAuth" but Facebook uses [OAuth2.0](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-11) while Twitter uses [OAuth1.0a](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/).  There is a substantial difference between the two.

In the end, Twitter logins weren't implemented because there's an awful lot of complexity required to do it properly and I think we got a good spread of login providers with just Facebook being added.

Naturally, if Twitter were to make an OAuth2.0 service available I'd be tempted to add it to `/users/login`.

Comment: Interesting stuff, I didn't realize Twitter doesn't support oAuth 2.0,  I don't support you have any useful links as to how Facebook has their stuff setup?

Comment: @bob the minute Twitter supports OAuth 2.0, we will add them, but not before. OAuth 1.0 is kind of nightmarish.

Comment: @Bob - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ documents Facebook OAuth.  Its really, really simple.  A basic consumer could probably be written in a dozen lines of code or so; ours is a bit bigger due to dealing with multiple domains (which is weird) and multiple deployment tiers (which is not so weird).

Comment: @Jeff Understood, I've never used either version so I'll trust your judgement :) @Kevin Cool stuff, thanks for the link!

Comment: I'm pretty sure Twitter now does support oAuth 2.0, perhaps worth revisiting?

Comment: +1 Cool information.  I thought about this, however this is wealthy information.  Thank you.

Comment: @TimPost They support application-only OAuth 2.0 (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth), which is based on the Client Credentials Grant (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.4). Looks like enough though.