# Why twitter is not an option for login in Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, login, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable authentication via Twitter (oAuth)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74551/enable-authentication-via-twitter-oauth)

Just wanted to know, that why stackoverflow team not included twitter as an option to login in SO and other stackexchange sites. Is there any reason?

mostly all the options are given but not twitter in login form: https://stackoverflow.com/users/login

I want to implement similar system in my app, but when I noticed twitter is not in SO's login list, so just wanted to know the reason, why? I am sure there is some valid reason as its hard to forget twitter while creating a social login form :)

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be the same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74551/enable-authentication-via-twitter-oauth